# Error Type 'XmlDsigC14NTransform' is not defined

Tags: vb.net, cryptography, c14n

My code starts with:

```
Imports System.Security.Cryptography
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.IO
```

But when I try to normalise my XML document using C14N:

```
 Dim c14n = New XmlDsigC14NTransform
```

I get an error:

> Code BC30002 Type 'XmlDsigC14NTransform' is not defined

I have used the same code before without errors.  I'm using target framework .NET Framework 4 Client Profile, is it likely I'm missing a reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't already done so, you need to add a reference to `System.Security`. Then add `Imports System.Security.Cryptography.Xml` to your list of imports (or fully qualify `XmlDsigC14NTransform`.

The Namespace and assembly is documented in [MSDN's article on XmlDsigC14NTransform](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.xml.xmldsigc14ntransform%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Comment: I'd added a reference to System.Security, but adding the missing Imports System.Security.Cryptography.Xml  fixed it, thank you